# Open background tab from extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to open tab in background so that user will not be interrupted and will continue to work where he was or even in some other application. I've tried

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://google.com", active: false, selected: false })
```

but it doesn't work - browser switches to newly created tab.

Comment: The code is correct and it works as it should. The only explanation for the problem is that something else is modifying the tab. For example some browsers may have a setting to override behavior of newly opened tabs. Or you have another extension that modifies behavior of newly opened tabs or there's another code in your extension that does exactly that in chrome.tabs.onCreated listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm, solved the problem. It was a bit more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Close devtools.

The code in the question is correct and Chrome opens background tab. Unless you opened devtools for debugging extention. If these devtools are an active window, Chrome will switch to newly opened tab anyway.